# How to set default zoom value of pdf response in java

Tags: java, rest, jersey, pdf-generation

I have written restful webservice which will return PDF file and this PDF will be appearing in IFrame in browser.
This part is good going.

But, the thing on which I am facing difficulties is, PDF file is opening on browser with selected zoom vale 'Automatic Zoom' but I wanted to show this PDF with zoom value 'Page Width' selected.
Please find below method which return PDF.

```
/**
* @param file
* @return Response object.
*/
private Response processRequest(final String filePath)
{

  File file = new File(filePath);

  PDPageFitDestination dest = new PDPageFitDestination();
  PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();    
  action.setDestination(dest);

  ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  PDDocument pd=null;
  try
  {
     pd = PDDocument.load(file);
     pd.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(action);
     pd.save(output);
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(COSVisitorException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

  //ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object)file);

  ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok(output.toByteArray());
  responseBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/pdf; filename=return.pdf");
  responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "inline");
  return responseBuilder.build();
  }
```

I think by providing any header value specific to zoom value will return PDF with zoom value 'Page Width' but not getting which header related to it.
Please provide your suggestions in this regard.

Comment: What browser/PDF viewer are you testing with? Not all browsers/PDF viewers will support opening a PDF to a specified zoom level. Adobe Acrobat accomplishes this through using an "Open Action".

Comment: @BrandonHaugen Thanks for your interest in my question. Currently I am working on "Mozilla Firefox 24" and for opening PDF "Adobe Acrobat Reader 11" is using.

Comment: @BrandonHaugen I have implemented as per your suggestion but still pdf is opening with Automatic Zoom rather than Page Width as default zoom value. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Just I needed to use pdf specific parameters in request URL. For detail go to [PDFOpenParameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf)